# Avoid containers to shutdown if machine is rebooted

Tags: macos, docker, persist

I have a OSX, and I would like to know if is possible to persist a container between OS reboots. I'm currently using my machine to host my code and using it to install platforms or languages like Node.js and Golang. I would like to create my environment inside a container, and also leave my code inside it, but without losing the container if my machine reboots. Is it possible? I didn't find anything related.

Comment: i dont know where you have been looking but here is something :-) https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: What @MazelTov said should be the way to go. Also, use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to persist your data between each container reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your container never killed if your system reboot except you start container with --rm which will remove on stop.
2. Your container will restart automatically if you start container with `docker run -dit --restart always my_container`
3. As per **" also leave my codes inside it"** this question is concern there is two solution to avoid loss of data or code and any other configuration.

You lose data because

> It is possible to store data within the writable layer of a container,
>   but there are some downsides:
>
> The data doesn’t persist when that container is no longer running, and
>   it can be difficult to get the data out of the container if another
>   process needs it.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/

**So here is the solution.**

> Docker offers three different ways to mount data into a container from
>   the Docker host: volumes, bind mounts, or tmpfs volumes. When in
>   doubt, volumes are almost always the right choice. Keep reading for
>   more information about each mechanism for mounting data into
>   containers.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/#good-use-cases-for-tmpfs-mounts

**Here how you can persist the nodejs code and golang code**

```
docker run -v /nodejs-data-host:/nodejs-container -v /go-data-host:/godata-container -dit  your_image
```

As per packages|runtimes (nodejs and go) is the concern they persist if your container killed or stop because they store in docker image.